# Why are the people I've circled not showing up?

Tags: google-plus, profile

How come the number of people shown "in your circles" on my page are only half of what I actually have?

Comment: Does it match the number of people in "Friends" circle + number of people in "Acquaintance" circle?

Answer (score 1):

Circles can take a few hours (maybe a day) to show up in your circles.

Also a maximum of around 5k people can be shown in that list.